# Finding number of combinations possible

Tags: algorithm, theory

I have a problem that is baffling me. I think there's an elegant solution, but I haven't been able to find it yet. The problem is as such:

I have a set of unique items. I am allowed to pick a maximum of **n** items from this set, to form a sub-set. The question then is, *how many unique sub-sets are possible*?

Say I have this set of **3** items:

```
A B C
```

And I am allowed to pick a maximum of **2** items from the set. The answers would be:

```
(none)
A
B
C
AB
AC
BC
```

That is, the answer is **7**. There are 7 unique sub sets possible.

How do I get to that solution pro grammatically?

If it matters, my sets have up to 8 items, and the maximum number of items on my answers is up to 3. They vary, though, hence why I wanted to see if there's an easier, more elegant way to get to this without brute force counting.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. What language do you want to do this in? If you want pseudocode, show us what you've done so far. Additionally, look into [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), which it sounds like you're looking for.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: actually, you can also pick no item which makes 7 unique subsets in the example.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are looking for the formula for the binomial coifficient. - (n choose k). In your case you can also choose onli 1 element so you have to add the number of elements to the formula in order to get the right answer, so the formula should end up being: (n choose k) +  n+ 1. [example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283+choose+2%29+%2B+3+%2B+1)

Comment: Henry: you're absolutely correct. I missed it. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: "Combination", uh. I was thinking my inability to solve this problem is because I lack the nomenclature to do a proper search. Who would've thought that would be the right one. Investigating this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the number of ways to choose at most k items from n, then you can sum the binomial coefficients n choose i for i from 0 to k, e.g.,

```
static int ways(int n, int k) {
  int sum = 0, nci = 1, i;
  for (i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
    sum += nci;
    nci *= n - i;
    nci /= i + 1;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you did, but I just tested that with my data and that is absolutely correct. Thank you everyone about about the other tips too. I have much to study to understand this now.

Comment: David, please explain how this code sums the binominals. Thanks.

Comment: I see it now. The binomial coefficient solves this problem quite elegantly. I'll let David edit the answer, but in short: you find **k** items in a set of **n** items by `n!/((k!)^2)` so I just had to find the sum of all possible values of **k**.

Comment: @NikoDrašković We have n choose i = n * (n - 1) * ... * (n - (i - 1)) / (1 * 2 * ... * i) = n/1 * (n - 1)/2 * (n - 2)/3 * ... * (n - (i - 1))/i.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Oh, I see now. You're moving through them, remembering the values of the previous calculations (fractions) to use in multiplying the next one. Brilliant!

Comment: Yep, it's a pretty nice optimization of the algorithm.